# MySQL query: select all if REGEXP $var is empty?

Tags: php, mysql, regex, select

```
$cities = "Amsterdam|Rotterdam|Den Haag"
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE content REGEXP '$cities'");
```

The above code works great, but if `$cities` is empty, nothing is selected. I'd like to select all rows if `$cities` has no value. How can I achieve that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use a conditional in your php, which removes the where clause when your `$cities` variable is empty. Alternatively, you can use a regex that matches everything like `/^/`, but it's not particularly elegant.

Comment: Right, if-else would do :P What was I thinking?? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you should check to see if the $cities is empty. If it is you can replace it with .* (match everything) or remove the from clause from the query (would increase performance)

Answer (score 0):

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages". 
(empty($cities)? "":" WHERE content REGEXP '$cities'"));
```

Or probably

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE '$cities' = '' OR content REGEXP '$cities'");
```